add icon to QSpinBox
i need to draw something like this:

I've done button styling with stylesheet, but I cannot draw the warning icon. Is there some way to add it without reimplementation of paintEvent()? If it's possible only with changing paintevent, how should it look like?

Can you specify the icon as a Unicode character inside the text string itself?  Eg use this Unicode character:  https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+26A0

QSpinBox embeds a QLineEdit, which supports addAction(). Just create a dummy QAction with your icon, and use spinBox->lineEdit()->addAction(action, QLineEdit::TrailingPosition).

when I try to add an action it says "lineedit is a protected member of QAbstractSpinBox"

@jdenv Then try to access it through findChild(QLineEdit).

@jdenv Good, you're welcome. I suggest you to answer your own question (click the related button in this page) by providing a brief explanation of what you did and a basic [mre].

I tried to add a QAction with an icon, but it couldn't be placed correctly. So the final solution is as simple as it is dumb, but it works:
okSpinBoxStylesheet=            "QDoubleSpinBox{"
                                            "border: 1px solid grey;"
                                            "border-radius: 8px;"
                                            "margin-right: 20px;"
                                            "background-color: white;"
                                            "font: 12px Manrope;"
                                            "padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;""}"
alertSpinBoxStyleSheet=         "QDoubleSpinBox{"
                                            "border: 1px solid grey;"
                                            "border-radius: 8px;"
                                            "margin-right: 20px;"
                                            "background: url(:/rsc/img/alertBack.png);"
                                            "background-position: right center;"
                                            "font: 12px Manrope;"
                                            "padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;""}"
                                    

alertBack looks like this:

When I need an icon, I just apply proper stylesheet
